# Is using IllegalArgumentException correct if field is wrong?

Tags: java

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Alpha{
   public int x;
   public Alpha(int x){ this.x = x; }
}
```

and a method which consumes `Alpha`.

```
public void method(Alpha alpha){
   if(alpha.x < 5 || alpha.x > 7){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(...); //IS THIS CORRECT USAGE?
   }

}
```

Is this usage correct? Technically the `Alpha` instance is not incorrect, but a field of that is incorrect. What to do?

Comment: Nothing specifically wrong here. Depends on how you would model your domain